# Infinite Loops: int vs. float

Tags: c, loops, floating-point

I'm working on a homework assignment and am probably psyching myself out about this thing a little too much, so I am just seeking some input. Here's the basic code:

```
for(x = 100; x > 0; x = x + x) {
    sum = sum + x;
```

There are two versions: one where `x` is a `float` and one where it is an `int`. The question is are these infinite loops.

I am thinking that when `x` is an `int`, it will eventually overflow, making it less than zero and the loop will stop.  When `x` is a `float`, `x` will reach infinity and the loop will be infinite.

Am I close?

Comment: Make sure you tag homework question with a homework tag.

Comment: There isn't a variable type that will ever hit an infinity, even the float for this example will have overflow and go negative. This sounds more like a math limit question. If you used unsigned variable types and did some checking for a 0 value, then these would run forever then.

Comment: @E-Z, I love it when people who don't know what they're talking about talk with such conviction. http://ideone.com/Ey4w6

Comment: An infinite loop is UB.  Somebody will get tired of it and delete your program.

Answer (score 8):

The behavior when a signed integer is increased beyond its limit is undefined. So the loop may end or it may be infinite. Or it may crash (or the loop may never run at all). Or as some C gurus like to say, demons may fly out of your nose - though personally I doubt any compiler implementor would go through the trouble of implementing nasal demon functionality.

As far as floating point values are concerned, you are correct that it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Or the loop may never run at all. :-) Since invoking UB is global in time, i.e. it affects everything "before" the UB was invoked as well.

Comment: I thought this was merely unspecified rather than undefined. I believe you, but do you have a standard ref? (Just want to find the wording myself so that I remember)

Comment: It's the first example of undefined behavior where undefined behavior is first defined, in 3.4.3.

Answer (score 3):

When signed integer overflows, the behavior is undefined. Expecting that `x` will become negative is naive at best.

Some compilers (like GCC) actually implement so called *strict value semantics*, which means that the compiler takes advantage of that undefined behavior for optimization purposes. In your specific example, the compiler might immediately generate a straightforward infinite loop, i.e. a loop that doesn't have any termination condition at all.

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed correct, integers will overflow to negative values (as long as they're signed) so the loop will end, and floats will stick to "+infinity" which is always greater than any number except `NaN`.

Edit: I stand corrected, the `int` version *does* loop infinitely (on some compilers due to their assumptions): http://ideone.com/HZkht

Comment: "integers will overflow to negative values" That is not guaranteed behavior.

Comment: OK, you go find a counter example!

Comment: A modern compiler will optimize the integer loop to an infinite loop.

Comment: Because an integer WILL overflow past `MAX_INT`. You can down-vote all you want, it won't make you right.

Comment: @Blindy: What do you mean "because"? If integer overflow were guaranteed to result in a negative integer, then surely optimizing that loop into an infinite loop would be wrong. So why would compilers perform that optimization *because* integers are guaranteed to overflow to negative values?

Comment: Btw: The "signed integer overflow" section of this article seems relevant here: [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: Hm this is decidedly odd (in my opinion at least), GCC4 really does optimize the first one into an infinite loop. I learned something new today!

Comment: Wrapping is only guaranteed for unsigned types. Signed overflow is not guaranteed to do anything; indeed, some compiler optimizations *rely* on it being undefined. See example at http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: I don't mean to be a nitpicker or anything, but that edit should probably read "the `int` version **can** loop infinitely" or "the `int` version *does* loop infinitely *with some compilers*", it certainly doesn't have to loop infinitely.

Comment: Fair enough, I updated it. I still think no compiler should "optimize" this however. What is even the point of it, if people write code like this, they most likely know what they're doing and expect an overflow.

Comment: @Blindy: It's not always people that wrote the code. For example when the compiler inlines code, it often ends up with conditions that are trivially true (or false) in the given context. Optimizing those away is a good area for optimization (often allowing you to even further optimize the function). If you prohibit the compiler from assuming that e.g. `x + positive_integer > x` a lot of potential for optimization is lost.

Comment: Also: a C programmer that knows what he's doing won't invoke undefined behavior unless he knows exactly what his compiler will do with that (and has a good reason for writing compiler-dependent code).

Comment: `x + positive_integer > x` still strikes me as a wrong assumption for any `x`. Since it's undefined behavior, why would the compiler encounter this so much that it needs special casing? I can't think of a single example of me using this in a program...

Comment: @Blindy: It's only undefined when `x + positive_integer` is greater than MAX_INT, which the compiler can't know. The point is that you might be doing something like `f(x,y) { if(x > y) {foo} else {bar} }` and then call it as e.g. `f(x, x+1)`. Now if the compiler inlines this, it ends up with `if(x > x+1) {foo} else {bar}`, which it can then optimize to just `bar`. In the majority of cases (which don't involve overflow), this is a perfectly valid optimization and does not go against the expectation of the programmer.

Comment: Is it really though? When would you write that? When DID you write anything like that?

Comment: @Blindy: When would I write `if(x,y) {foo} else {bar}`? Plenty of cases. The `gcd` function comes to mind. Admittedly I wouldn't usually call `gcd(x,x+1)`, but there are plenty of cases where I'd call `gcd(x,y)` in a situation where the compiler knows which one of `x` and `y` is greater.